# Set UITableViewCell height *without* using heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, height

I'm trying to set the height of a UITableViewCell based on some dynamic content.  I know you can "set" the height via the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method in your view controller, but... I can't do that!

The problem is that the height of the cell isn't known until cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, and heightForRowAtIndexPath is called *before* cellForRowAtIndexPath.

So, I need to somehow either reverse the order in which these two methods are called, or find another way to set the cell height.

Any ideas?

Comment: Either you have to calculate the height in `viewDidLoad` and add it in an array and use it or do the calculation in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. You cant reverse the order.

Comment: Whatever computations you're doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath to get the height, why can't you do those same computations in heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @ACB is right (as usual!). You have to do it this way round. You need to rethink how or when you are calculating the row height - it should be based on  your model, which should be known before you start describing your table view. _Why_ can't you do it in the normal order?

Comment: @jrturton, Thanks for the kind words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - there's no built-in way to reverse those methods or anything similar. One of the reasons is that a table view can want to know the height of a row for a number of reasons, not all of which include displaying a cell - `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` might get called several times, or `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` might not get called at all following a call to the height method.

What you *can* do is find another way to compute the appropriate height ahead of time, cache it, and rely on that cached value for `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. I've managed to do something similar by constructing a "dummy" UITableViewCell instance, keeping it out of the normal reuse queue, and just using it for layout and height-determination purposes. Such a solution would go something like this:

1. Get `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.
2. Look up the index path in your height cache. If you have a value, return it.
3. Otherwise, use your dummy cell to lay out the content that would appear at that index path. Measure the cell's height and cache it.
4. Potentially repeat steps 1-3 several times, depending on how much `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.
5. Get `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
6. Dequeue a cell from the normal reuse queue, populate it, lay it out, and return it. (You may choose to verify that its height matches your precomputed height, so that the table view behaves how you'd expect.)

Depending on the content of your cell and the complexity of the phrase "lay it out" in your use case, this may incur a reasonable performance hit as you calculate the first several heights, or as your users scroll your table view rapidly. However, as your cache warms up, you should be computing fewer and fewer heights as your app continues to run.

One last point: remember that for cells with default heights (which may or may not appear in your table), you can early-out by returning `tableView.rowHeight`, rather than computing the default height every time it appears. This can ease the computation burden of the above approach somewhat.